# Can I disable a single pole thermostat by disconnecting it?

Tags: thermostat

I have a single pole thermostat that controls some baseboard heaters in a garage. The previous owner used the garage as a workshop, so it made sense to keep it heated, but I don't use it at all, so I want to disable it so it's not wasting electricity. Can I just disconnect the wires from the thermostat, and put wire nuts on each wire, and shove it all back in there? Can this be easily replaced with a thermostat that turns it off? Thanks.

[image: thermostat]
[image: behind thermostat]

Comment: why not just turn the heater off at the breaker, no modification needed? To answer though, yes, the two wires are connected to request heat. That means you can replace it with a regular heavy-duty switch too, in case you might want to occasionally or in an emergency turn it on without messing with wires.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Is there a simple thermostat that has an "OFF" mode? I see that "double pole thermostats" have them, but it seems you can't just swap out a single pole thermostat with a double pole.

Comment: honeywell's CT410B and T498B1512 come up on amazon.

Comment: is there a water line in there? if so you want some heat to prevent the line from freezing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a line-voltage thermostat.  It is switching  240 volts AC mains voltage, *not* low voltage as in on a Nest or other gas furnace thermostat.

Many line-voltage thermostats are made with a hard “off” that switches power off regardless of temperature. You must turn the knob past a stiff “detent” and you feel a positive shutoff.

First, check the thermostat to see if it has that! Many people never push past the detent, and do not know it is there.

If not, buy one. Line voltage thermostats are cheap.

Note that this feature works inly on one pole of a 2-pole thermostat.  The other pole can turn on if it’s cold enough.  If you only have two wires going to the ‘stat, add a jumper to wire the two poles in series,,, so you get both thermostatic and hard-off control.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but if a 240v (or 208v) heater I advise against it. When the breaker is "on" the other leg will always be feeding through the heater and both wires that were connected to the stat will measure hot with a contact or non-contact meter, and can lead to some confusion later.

It would be much better to identify which cable is the feed and disconnect both hot wires. Disconnecting both leads also insures nobody inaccurately thinks (or remembers) that the heater has been completely de-energized when it hasn't.

There also several styles of breaker lock-off devices that also could be considered, some are available that don't interfere with the operation of the door. If the heaters are not in sight of the panel may be legally required anyway.

Comment: Many breaker lock-off devices are panel brand specific, the make of your panel would be needed for specific recommendation.